# I’m using Deserialization method to create an object getting Exception “NullPointerException”?

Tags: java

I was trying creating objects in four different ways for one class, however I can able to create objects in three ways. But whenever I’m using Deserialization method to create an object getting Exception “NullPointerException”.please let me know the possible ways to resolve that exception.

below is the code.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

class Student{
    private String name;

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String s){
        name=s;
    }
}
public class TestEncaps implements Cloneable{

    public void Testing(){
        System.out.println("Testing is On Going");
    }
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return  (TestEncaps) super.clone();
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws CloneNotSupportedException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     Student s = new Student();
     s.setName("Lakshmikantham");
     System.out.println(s.getName());

     TestEncaps te = new TestEncaps();

     TestEncaps te1 = (TestEncaps) te.clone();

     te1.Testing();
     te.Testing();

     try{
       InputStream inputStream = null;
        ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
        TestEncaps object4 = (TestEncaps) inStream.readObject();

        object4.Testing();
     }catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
     }finally{

     }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the serialized file as the input to the `InputStream` and pass its object to `ObjectInputStream`.

```
      TestEncaps object4 = null;
      FileInputStream inputFileStream = new FileInputStream("file.dat");
      ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputFileStream);
      object4 = (TestEncaps)objectInputStream.readObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that inputStream may be null in this code fragment:

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are creating an ObjectInputStream with null as parameter.

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
TestEncaps object4 = (TestEncaps) inStream.readObject();
```

to

```
InputStream inputStream = new InputStream("yourfile.obj");
ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
TestEncaps object4 = (TestEncaps) inStream.readObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

You lack three things,

1. Student class need to implement Serializable
2. You need to serialize it to file
3. You need to deserialize it from file

Check a quick example, should be enough to have you fix your issue on your own

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to *read an Object from a `null` Stream*

This is causing the Exception

```
 InputStream inputStream = null;
        ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
```

The ObjectInputStream is called a connection stream ,it can be connected with a I/O or network stream from which it can read serialized data , in your case you are saying literally

```
   ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(null);
```

and trying to read from `null` basically ,hence the *null pointer exception*

First try writing a few object into a Serialized file(.ser type) and then read from it or pass a already existing serialized file to the `ObjectInputStream` such as this

```
FileInputStream fs=new FileInputStream(""likeThis.ser");
ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(fs);
```

then read from it .